# Passing Strings between Classes

Tags: java, string

Fair new to java. Read a few other questions but haven't found the solution yet. Im looking to pass *acname*, *dob* and *balance1* (all input by the user) to another class. currently it results in nullnullnull. Please help:

First Class:

```
public static String acname;
public static String dob;
public static String balance1;

public static void main(String[] args) {

            switch (menu) {

            case 1: Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("Please enter account holders name:");

                    String acname = sc.nextLine();

                    Scanner sc2=new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("Please enter account holders date of birth:");

                    String dob = sc2.nextLine();

                    BankAccount balance1 = new BankAccount(0, 0.10);
                    balance1.getBalance();

                    System.out.println("Account Created. Overview and Balance: " + "\n" + acname + "\n" + dob + "\n" + "£" + balance1.getBalance() + "\n");
```

Second Class:

```
public class MainMenu {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("--WELCOME TO BEAN BANKING LTD--");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("1. Create new account");
    System.out.println("2. View account details and balance");
    System.out.println("3. Deactivate account");
    System.out.println("4. Exit System");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int menu = scanner.nextInt();

    switch (menu) {
        case 1: AccountCreator.main(null);
        case 2: System.out.println(AccountCreator.acname + AccountCreator.dob + AccountCreator.balance1);
```

Comment: Please show a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) that actually demonstrates the problem. You aren't showing enough code.

Comment: Those are two separate applications, they do not share memory. When MainMenu is instantiated in the JVM, the static Strings in First Class is instantiated to null. You are scanning the values for those strings in another application. If you want to have it shared, you will have to add the scanner code of first class to the case 2: of MainMenu

Comment: It might be helpfull to run through some of [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). Specifically [Object-Oriented Programming Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html) will help you on how to pass information between classes

Comment: This is may not be the answer but first use break statement after each of your case statements otherwise the subsequent cases will be executed. For example if user has chosen menu 1, all of other codes for menu 2,3,4 ... will be executed after that.

Comment: @MrRho Actually, MainMenu is calling the main method of AccountCreator.  This isn't a good way to do things but you have to start somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring local variables with the same names as your class variables.  The local variables will be assumed unless you qualify references to them.

Instead of:

```
String acname = sc.nextLine();
```

Just do:

```
acname = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: Also, it still won't help if you don't press 1 before 2 in the MainMenu class. Perhaps add an initialisation flag so that if you press 2 and 1 hasn't been selected display an error message such as: "No existing accounts found"